# Whenever i create app with internet permission it only works when installed from android studio.Not as apk why so?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, android-install-apk

When i create application which needs internet permission it only works when installed from android studio.When i share this application usnig sharing app or share apk of it ,it crashes on opening("unfortunately stopped").Why??

This is the manifest of my one of the application that crashes when installed from apk.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="safmical.h">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Login" />
        <activity
            android:name=".splashscreen"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <!-- <activity android:name=".forgetpassword" />
        -->
        <activity
            android:name="fragments.h.safmical.IndividualUser_Safmical"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_safmical"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!--<activity android:name=".list2" />
        <activity android:name=".listone" />-->
        <activity
            android:name="fragmentscompany.h.safmical.Company_Safmical"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_company__safmical"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "individualuser_safmical.h"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Logcat shows:

```
05-24 18:25:22.038 27611-27611/individualuser_safmical.h E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: individualuser_safmical.h, PID: 27611
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{individualuser_safmical.h/safmical.h.splashscreen}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "safmical.h.splashscreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/individualuser_safmical.h-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "safmical.h.splashscreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/individualuser_safmical.h-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1089)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
                                                                            Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: safmical.h.splashscreen
                                                                               at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                    ... 13 more
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Please help,i am stuck with this problem.

In other phones logcat:

```
05-24 19:50:20.176 19467-19467/individualuser_safmical.h E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: individualuser_safmical.h, PID: 19467
                                                                           java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getContext()Landroid/content/Context; in class Lfragmentsstartup/hh/safmical/LoginFragment; or its super classes (declaration of 'fragmentsstartup.hh.safmical.LoginFragment' appears in /data/app/individualuser_safmical.h-1/base.apk)
                                                                               at fragmentsstartup.hh.safmical.LoginFragment$myasyncindividual.onPostExecute(LoginFragment.java:198)
                                                                               at fragmentsstartup.hh.safmical.LoginFragment$myasyncindividual.onPostExecute(LoginFragment.java:91)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: Share your crash log

Comment: Please check the device versions and clean your project

Comment: that may occur due to no internet connectivity on other phones check internet connection before you open app on other phones

Comment: In which real device OS(eg. Marshmallow) are you testing this app??

Comment: Lollipop - ER Vishal Senjaliya

Comment: the internet conncection is working perfectly-nithin y.n.v

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this error occurs because of the wrong version entry of appcompat-v7 library version in build.gradle at dependencies scope and throws ClassNotFound Exception like this-> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.buscaserra.main.ActivitySplash" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file

To get rid of this problem
Please write a proper and specific version of appcompat-v7 in dependencies scope like this->

Do not -
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'

Do -
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

Comment: I have added my gradle file.I think appcompact dependencies are correct.Is there any mistakes?

Comment: Okey, next thing you need to check in the AndroidManifest.xml file that you have declared the activities with full package name or not.
Do->
<activity 
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"/>
Do not->
 <activity 
            android:name=".MainActivity"/>

And one more thing... you need to build the APK from Build menu in Android Studio (Build -> Build APK)

Comment: yeh now it runs.But at some page it crashes and some page's xml user interface  also gets changed.Where all this is perfect when app installed from android studio.

Comment: Please run the APK on phone and then connect with your pc -> open Android Monitor -> Check the Error Log -> send me the error logs.

Comment: I have added error logs in field "other phones logcat".